# How to draw a function image within multiple interval definition domains?

Tags: functions

```
Plot[x^3, {x, -1, 3 || 7, 10}]
```

Note that the intervals of the function are separated. There are two intervals, (- 1,3) and (7,10)

Comment: `Plot[x^3, x ∈ Interval[{-1, 3}, {7, 10}]]`

Comment: What if a certain interval contains positive or negative infinity?

Comment: ```Plot[x^3, 
 x \[Element] Interval[{-1, 3}, {7, 10}, {20, 22}, {30, Infinity}]]```Why can't I draw a function image?

Comment: It is impossible to do this by `Interval`.  Now we can only using `Plot[x^3, {x, 30, ∞}]`

Comment: How do I draw an image with infinite functions in multiple intervals?

Comment: Do not ask questions in comments. If your original question did not adequately describe your problem then edit the question to amplify or clarify what your problem actually is. Ideally give sufficient thought to your question before you ask so that is does not need to be modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless, I completely misunderstood the question:

```mma
Show[{Plot[x^3, {x, -1, 3}], Plot[x^3, {x, 7, 10}]}, 
  PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```mma
Show[{Plot[x^3, {x, -1, 3}], Plot[x^3, {x, 7, 10}]}, 
  PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The following range does not play nice with other ranges.

```mma
Plot[x^3, {x, 30, Infinity}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Of course, I may have missed ormisunderstood something.